# Conflict with socket.io and browser-sync

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, gulp, browser-sync

I was working with my Angular files and viewed it using browser-sync in gulp. The Angular views won't load in the browser and throws an error in Chrome Console that pointed out socket.io.
These are the error messages:

```
  Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.2/$injector/nomod?p0=portfolio
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    GET http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1452587505197-14 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This is in my gulpfile

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');    
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
       var files = [
          '*.html',
          'css/**/*.css',
          'js/**/*.js'
       ];

       browserSync.init(files, {
          server: {
             baseDir: './'
          }
       });
    });
```

I tried  to use Live Preview in Brackets. Everything works fine with Angular. Is there something I need to change in my gulp files so it will load the Angular views?